# android app send data over the internet only when charging

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating an Android application that sends data to MySql database over the internet using background service. 
the application works perfectly when it is plugged to USB cable, once I remove the cable it keeps working except that it does not send the data to the server.
the following classes that are responsible for sending the data:
1. Save thread: will send the data periodically after checking the internet connection
2. ConnectionStatus checks if the app is connected to the internet or not
3. AsyncT responsible on sending the data

```
public class SaveThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
    Context context;
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    int currentsecond;
    int currentminut;
    int currenthour;

    public SaveThread (Context applicationContext) {
        context=applicationContext;
        startTimer();
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                currentsecond = rightNow.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                currentminut = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                currenthour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

                AppConstant.Hour = currenthour;
                AppConstant.Minuts = currentminut;
                AppConstant.Seconds =currentsecond;


                if (currentsecond%AppConstant.FREQ == 0) {
                    if (ConnectionStatus.getInstance(context).isConnectedTONetwork()) {
                        Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "You are online ^_^ ");
                        AsyncT asyncT = new AsyncT();
                        asyncT.execute();

                    } else {
                        Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "No internet connection !!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }}


public class ConnectionStatus {
    private static ConnectionStatus instance = new ConnectionStatus();
    static Context context;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;
    boolean connected = false;

    public static ConnectionStatus getInstance(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isConnectedTONetwork() {
        try {
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
            if (connected){
                connected = hasActiveInternetConnection();
            }
            return connected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CheckConnectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.v(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return connected;
    }

    public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}



public class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String ServerURL = XXXXXXXX;
    String responseServer;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();

            jsonobj.put("H", AppConstant.Hour);
            jsonobj.put("M", AppConstant.Minuts);
            jsonobj.put("S", AppConstant.Seconds);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("req", jsonobj.toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamToStringExample str = new InputStreamToStringExample();
            responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
            Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "response ------------------" + AppConstant.Collecting_date);
            Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "response ------------------" + responseServer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's because of Doze mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: @SergeyGlotov thanks for your response, but do you know any way to prevent that.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Thanks, you were right, you saved me thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you write an answer and describe how did you solve the issue for future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description that you are sending data periodically, WorkManager might be a better solution for you, especially since you are doing a lot yourself that the API already does for you. There are a lot of resources on how to use it, including [samples, code-labs and blogs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#additional-resources).